# iOS push notifications uses bundleID instead of app name

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, alerts, bundle-identifier

Is there any way to make the app use the app name instead of bundle id in the title of push notifications (alerts). The banners are OK and display the app name and app icon. But the alerts use the bundleID.

Answer (score 3):

iOS has a cache for the push notification settings (the prompt for them, name, etc), that gets refreshed once in a while.
Try changing the date (a day ahead) and/or rebooting the device, which will invalidate the cache and show the correct name.

Answer (score 2):

By default the Alert view title in the PushNotification displays the "Bundle Display name" from info.plist.